# How to say I kept a longer haircut

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

I went to the barber earlier today and asked for a haircut with my hair to be left longer than usual.

Then, when I am talking to someone else, can I say:

> I asked the barber to leave my hair longer.​
>
> I asked the barber not to cut my hair very short.​
>
> I left (or kept) my hair longer than usual.​

Comment: I would say "I asked him to cut my hair longer"?

Comment: I would say "I asked him not to cut it as short as usual" or "...as he usually does".

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. How about the third sentence in the quote? Could I perhaps go with 'I cut my hair longer than usual'?

Comment: You're (deliberately, I suspect! :) steering into "uncanny valley" semantic territory here! We'll end up asking whether I can say *I loosened my belt tighter than usual.*

Comment: Well, it's not deliberate, I promise! :D It's just that I am trying to figure out how to say that my hair is longer than usual after having a haircut and am strangely having no ideas that sound proper... I think that I will go with 'I had my hair longer than usual' and won't chase it any longer.

Comment: I would probably say "At the barbers, I didn't have as much off as usual".